# How to hide the menu Gnome/Xfce/GTK applications by default?

Tags: gnome, xfce, gtk, menu

I feel that the menu in most applications doesn't add enough benefit to have it shown by default.

Some individual applications support hiding the menu (and only showing it when pressing Alt, or a different key), but how do I configure this for all applications?